# XBMC with Media Player Classic Home Cinema

Tags: kodi

Does anybody have an example of `advancedsettings.xml` configuration in XBMC to have it use Media Player Classic Home Cinema as an external player for all types of video files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://xbmc.org/wiki/?title=HOW-TO_use_an_External_Player_for_media_playback) link has the answer, and the forum [thread](http://www.xbmc.org/forum/showthread.php?t=43511) is also useful.

Basically, an example with Media Player Classic Home Cinema:

```
<playercorefactory>
  <players>
    <player name="MPC-HC" type="ExternalPlayer" audio="false" video="true">
      <filename>C:\Program Files\MPC-HC\mplayerc.exe</filename>
      <args>/fullscreen /close</args>
      <hidexbmc>false</hidexbmc>
      <hideconsole>false</hideconsole>
      <hidecursor>false</hidecursor>
    </player>
  </players>
  <rules action="prepend">
    <rule filetypes="mkv" filename=".*720p.*" player="MPC-HC"/>
  </rules>
</playercorefactory>
```